# Multiple Models in One Controller in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have 2 Models, ComanyModel and Address Model. In the Company Model there is a AddressId which connects the two tables in the DB. I want to register a company and save the information is the Database in two separate tables. Now i want the user to enter the company information and the address in the same page but don't know how to go about doing it. I am able to do it in ASP, but now I am very new in MVC3.

Please advice me on how I can archive this.

Here are my two model classes:

public class CompanyModel

```
{

    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string DirectorName { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RegNo { get; set; }
    public string VatNo { get; set; }

}
```

public class AddressModel

```
{

    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Entity FrameWork?

Comment: This is how i save my data to the db.


using FusionXC.Data;


IDataOperations ops = DataSession.GetDataOperations(null);

List<DepartmentModel> deptModel = new List<DepartmentModel>();
           ops.Create(deptModel).Into("Department").Values(deptModel);
            ops.Commit();

Comment: I have a Business Layer, Data Layer and UI Layer, In the business Layer I have Models folder with classes identical to the ones in the DB and use them to save my data

Answer (score 6):

You have to create one viewModel for both table

for example:

```
public class nameViewModel
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

and then in View

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company.Name)

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.Name)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.Name)


 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.Name)

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Name)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.Name)
```

Comment: How do I create the ActionResult create method in the controller??

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ActionName(nameViewModel model)
        {
            // Actions
        }

Answer (score 0):

You need another class like this

```
public class CompanyAddressModel
{
public CompanyModel Company { get; set; }
public AddressModel Address { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Murat mentioned earlier you can create a new viewmodel and then access the instances of the classes with `@Model.Company` and `@Model.Address`. If you are lazy (like I am) you can create strongly typed views from each of the classes and then combine the views into one. Or you can create partial views from the classes and get them by `@Html.Action("CreateCompany", Model.Company)` or `@Html.Partial("CompanyView", Model.Company)`